# How do I tell Caddy which sub domain to use

Tags: lets-encrypt, caddy, caddyfile

I am trying to use Caddy for the first time. I want to be able to serve several subdomains. Caddy requests SSL certificates from Let's Encrypt. I have managed to get this to work ok with only one domain name in the caddyfile.

However, suppose I have

```
www.example.com, test.example.com {
    ...  lots of settings
}
```

I am relying on the Let's Connect server calling back into one of those subdomains (i.e. not using DNS TXT records). But this raises questions:

- Which one does Caddy use when it requests a certificate?
- Is there a way to specify which one I want it to use?

(In the example above there are just two subdomain, but actually I'd like to know how to get it to work with more than two.)

--
**EDIT**: When I try this on `test.example.com`, I get an error (note: I have concealed my actual domain names):

```
Activating privacy features...2016/11/21 07:47:41 [www.example.com] failed to get certificate: acme: Error 403 - urn:acme:error:unauthorized - Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ALmqQ8Vl5fvPF91tvqw2zigHlPoRRgTGR2GaLtgX3-A [134.92.240.68]: 404
```

Caddy prints more detail essentially repeating the same information, then it terminates.

Comment: Your DNS for each domain has to be pointing to where your server is.

Comment: ok that's clear, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In order to serve multiple subdomains, you can add them seperately to your [Caddyfile](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile). Caddy will request a distinct SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt for each domain name.

```
example.com {
  ...
}

www.example.com {
  ...
}

test.example.com {
  ...
}
```

→ 3 distinct certificates: [example.com] [www.example.com] [test.example.com]

You can combine multiple addresses that share the same configuration like you did in your example, but Caddy will still request one SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt for each specified domain name.

```
www.example.com, test.example.com {
  ...
}
```

→ 2 distinct certificates: [www.example.com] [test.example.com]

Comment: This is not what happens - see additional info in the question.